# Twitter Authorization

Tags: java, rest, twitter, oauth, unirest

For 2 days I've tried to do a request with unirest (I have to use it) to Twitter but I'm not getting good feedback from rest of what I'm doing wrong.

This is my request:

```
    HttpResponse request = Unirest.post( "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json" )
            .header( "Authorization",
                    "oauth_consumer_key=\"XXX\"," +
                            "oauth_token=\"XXX\"," +
                            "oauth_signature=\"XXX\"" +
                            "oauth_nonce=\"XXX\"," +
                            "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\"," +
                            "oauth_timestamp=\"1467448738\"," +
                            "oauth_version=\"1.0\","
            )
            .header( "Content-Type", "application/json" )
            .header( "accept", "application/json" )
            .header( "X-Target-URI", "https://api.twitter.com" )
            .header( "Host", "api.twitter.com" )
            .header( "Connection", "Keep-Alive" ).asJson();
```

And I'm getting

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

With this page it's easy to do https :// apigee.com/console/twitter but I see 
oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature are random generated every time.  (Do I have to generate them somehow?)

http :// quonos.nl/oauthTester/ - this site was helping me to check oauth signature

And this https :// dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator/<+my id> generated for me Signature base string, Authorization header, cURL command

I have also keys from https :// apps.twitter.com/app/
    Consumer Key (API Key)
    Consumer Secret (API Secret)
    Access Token
    Access Token Secret
(And Access Read, write, and direct messages)

But every time I'm getting an error.

So whats wrong with my code? Do I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oauth_timestamp isn't randomly generated, it is the current time.  e.g. your example above is (verify with http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

```
Sat, 02 Jul 2016 08:38:58 GMT
```

oauth_nonce is random as described in the help page below, e.g. "base64 encoding 32 bytes of random data".

oauth_signature is calculated based on your request parameters, sometimes post body, the client token/secret etc.

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures

This is some example code for signing requests
https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/release/1.4/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/services/twitter/Signature.java

Comment: The last link is not avaialble !

Comment: i followed the process https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures still the api is throwing "BAD authentication data. "

Comment: @SantanuSur You can check an example of complete code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765764/1776132