# How to get twitter accessToken from java?

Tags: api, twitter

I'm creating a web application which needs some details of the user's twitter account. How can I get the twitter accessToken and access the twitter API. When I was searching this, I found that I had to create my application in twitter developers site Which I dont want at all. I've created my simple web application in java, in which i need to use twitter API. Is that possible??? Please help me out.

Comment: You should use Twitter4j library. If you want to connect to Twitter API without any library, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765764/1776132

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange work best when you have a specific code question that we can clarify for you. This question is very broad so it is less simple to provide you with a direct solution.

In order to access the details of a user's Twitter account, you need to use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/). Twitter uses OAuth for authentication, so you'll need to code the login flow to get a user accessToken. You also need to register an app with Twitter on [apps.twitter.com](https://apps.twitter.com) in order to get a consumerKey and consumerSecret to uniquely identify your app.

Since you're using Java, you might find [Twitter4J](https://twitter4j.org) a useful library for helping you with this. It comes with some pretty good samples that should help you to understand what you'll need to build.