# How to generate oauth_token from twitter request token API

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm creating an app in which I need to post tweets in twitter on behalf of different users. So, I using Application User authentication. For me to redirect the user to twitter page to provide access I need oauth_token from twitter. 
For that I am using [Request_token_api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/request_token). 
But everytime am getting could not authenticate you and the twitter api page says authorization is not required for this API

I tried using many libraries like passport, Twit, OAuth, etc.. But nothing worked and I am pretty sure all my developer account consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret are correct.

```
function getAuthorization(httpMethod, baseUrl, reqParams) {
  // Get acces keys

  const consumerKey       = keysJson.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
      consumerSecret      = keysJson.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
      accessToken         = keysJson.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      accessTokenSecret   = keysJson.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET;
  // timestamp as unix epoch
  let timestamp  = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  // nonce as base64 encoded unique random string
  let nonce      = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64').replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '') ;
  let cburl = percentEncode(keysJson.cb);
  // generate signature from base string & signing key
  let baseString = oAuthBaseString(httpMethod, baseUrl, reqParams, consumerKey, accessToken, timestamp, nonce);
  console.log(baseString);
  let signingKey = oAuthSigningKey(consumerSecret, accessTokenSecret);
  // console.log(signingKey);
  let signature  = oAuthSignature(baseString, signingKey);
  console.log(signature);
  // return interpolated string
  return 'OAuth '                                         +
      'oauth_nonce="'         + nonce             + '", ' +
      'oauth_callback="'      + cburl             + '", ' +
      'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", '              +
      'oauth_timestamp="'     + timestamp         + '", ' +
      'oauth_consumer_key="'  + consumerKey       + '", ' +
      'oauth_signature="'     + signature         + '", ' +
      'oauth_version="1.0"'                               ;
}

function oAuthBaseString(method, url, params, key, token, timestamp, nonce) {
  return method
          + '&' + percentEncode(url)
          + '&' + percentEncode(genSortedParamStr(params, key, token, timestamp, nonce));
};


function oAuthSigningKey(consumer_secret, token_secret) {
  return consumer_secret + '&' + token_secret;
};


function oAuthSignature(base_string, signing_key) {
  var signature = hmac_sha1(base_string, signing_key);
  return percentEncode(signature);
};

function percentEncode(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!*()']/g, (character) => {
    return '%' + character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
};

function hmac_sha1(string, secret) {
  let shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-1", "TEXT");
  shaObj.setHMACKey(secret, "TEXT");
  shaObj.update(string);
  let hmac = shaObj.getHMAC("B64");
  return hmac;
};

function mergeObjs(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var attr in obj2) {
      obj1[attr] = obj2[attr];
  }
  return obj1;
};


function genSortedParamStr(params, key, token, timestamp, nonce)  {
  // Merge oauth params & request params to single object
  let paramObj = mergeObjs(
      {
          include_entities: 'true',
          oauth_consumer_key : key,
          oauth_nonce : nonce,
          oauth_signature_method : 'HMAC-SHA1',
          oauth_timestamp : timestamp,
          // oauth_token : token,
          oauth_version : '1.0'
      },

  );
  // Sort alphabetically
  let paramObjKeys = Object.keys(paramObj);
  let len = paramObjKeys.length;
  paramObjKeys.sort();
  // Interpolate to string with format as key1=val1&key2=val2&...
  let paramStr = paramObjKeys[0] + '=' + paramObj[paramObjKeys[0]];
  for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
      paramStr += '&' + paramObjKeys[i] + '=' + percentEncode(decodeURIComponent(paramObj[paramObjKeys[i]]));
  }
  return paramStr;
};



var redirect_uri = encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:4200/admin/marketing/loginsuccess');

 var auth = getAuthorization('POST','https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',{oauth_callback:redirect_uri});

 console.log(auth);

 var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "api.twitter.com",
    "port": null,
    "path": '/oauth/request_token',
    "headers": {
         'Authorization' : auth 
      }
  };

  try {
    console.log(options);
        var req = https.request(options, function (res1) {
          var chunks = [];
          console.log('statusCode:', res1.statusCode);
          console.log('headers:', res1.headers);

          res1.on("data", function (chunk) {
          chunks.push(chunk);
          });

          res1.on("end", function () {
          var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
          var disp = JSON.parse(body.toString());
          console.log(disp);
        });
      });  
      req.end();
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({success:false,message:error});
  }
```

I need the oauth access token from Twitter API but am getting.

```
{ errors: [ { code: 32, message: 'Could not authenticate you.' } ] }
```

I am struggling for 3 days. Kindly let me know is there any alternate way to implement twitter API in nodejs or some sample code in github.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MaxFraire You can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765764/1776132